# Saving password in rdp file | Windows 7

Tags: windows, rdp

Windows do not allow saving password in rdp files. Even if I select "Allow me to save credentials" while connection via Remote Desktop Connection.

After searching a lot, I found that it requires modifying entry "Do not allow passwords to be saved" to "Disabled" in Group Policy under Computer Configuration -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Connection Client.

However, after doing so it is still not allowing me to save password. Let me know if there's some other setting that needs to be done.

Comment: Stackoverflow is about questions involving programming, what you are asking about fits into [Superuser.com](http://superuser.com/) much better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please follow the steps in [this link](https://superuser.com/a/140322).

You can have a look at the image:

[image]